# Source Tracked vs Non-Source-Tracked org

Tags: salesforcedx, sourcecontrol, source

What's the difference between these 2 kind of orgs?

It seems Trailhead Playgrounds orgs I am creating are non-source-tracked org and certain CLI commands can't be run against it.

How I can identify them, create a source tracking org and what exactly is the difference between them?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Source tracking is available in scratch orgs, and, as of [Summer '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_sandboxes_source_tracking.htm), is in beta for Developer and Developer Pro sandboxes if the optional feature is enabled in Setup.

Source tracking makes it possible to use the `sfdx force:source:pull` and `force:source:push` commands (and their GUI equivalents), which automatically identify changed metadata components between your local source tree and the remote org.

Without source tracking, you must use manifest-based deployments using a `package.xml` manifest with commands like `sfdx force:source:deploy`. This entails creating and managing a manifest to define which specific components you wish to interact with.

Trailhead Playgrounds do not currently have source tracking. They are a type of Developer Edition org (not a sandbox). They can, however, be Dev Hubs, which allow you to create scratch orgs.

Comment: You can make an org a source-tracking org by enabling 'DEV HUB' thing?

Comment: No, not quite. Turning on Dev Hub allows you to create scratch orgs from the Dev Hub, and they have source tracking. The Dev Hub does not. There's a setting in the Dev Hub section to turn on source tracking for associated Developer and Developer Pro sandboxes as well.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi guys, I just turned this option on, according to this article: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_setup_enable_source_tracking_sandboxes.htm
But I still receive same error from this thread while using push command against sandbox. What else do I need to do, anything with sandbox, refresh it?

Comment: Ho @patryk, yes yo do need to refresh your sandbox.